# Method not found execption when creating Azure.Storage.Blobs Container C# Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I try and create a container or check if a container with the same name already exists in C# using Azure.Storage.Blobs Nuget package in Xamarin Forms it throws the following exeception:

`System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: void Azure.Core.RequestUriBuilder.AppendPath(System.ReadOnlySpan1<char>,bool)'`

This is the code that is throwing the exception:

```
// Define the connection string for the Azure Blob Storage.
string connectionString = App.carterAccountStorageConnection;
BlobContainerClient container = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerName);

// Create the container if it does not exist.
ontainer.CreateIfNotExists(PublicAccessType.Blob);
```

I have checked the connectionString which is correct and the container name which is also correct.
This code when used on my .NET C# application works perfectly but on the Xamarin forms app it returns the exception.

I have tried checking if the container exists first using:

```
if (!await container.ExistsAsync())
{
   container.create();
}
```

but this didn't work either.